# Adding and Subtracting Values- Across Time and In Order

Tags: postgresql

New to PostgresQL and haven't been able to figure out how to approach the following situation:

Background:
Say you have a production plant data that starts from 2014-01-01 that produces some kind of Oil. You know every day it'll produce X amount of oil. You also know the production started from before 2014-01-01, but that's the data you have. Our table does not contain a day to day production log, but only information on the plant, it's production per day, and it's total capacity.

The table storing the plant info contains these columns/data types:

```
plant_name text, #there will be multiple plants involved in this
storage_capacity integer,
daily_production integer;
```

You know that something is going to arrive every day to take oil from the plant, and they are each going to have a unique size and amount they take from the tanker. You know what those sizes and amounts are.

the table with the arrivals will look like this:

```
vessel_id integer,
plant_arrive text,
date_arrive timestamp;
```

and will be joined with another table on vessel_id to gain this row:

```
vessel_capacity int;
```

I am trying to build a correct history of exactly how these transactions occurred, with the intent being to find out exactly how much oil exists at each plant right now, today. In order to do that, what i'm imagining I need is to add each X as every day passes (until it reaches a capacity number) with a new table that enumerates over the date (or something like that), and subtract from that X whenever something arrives to take from it. I don't need to do this as a difference of total sum of days - total sum of oil capacity from arrivals, but as a day by day, arrival by arrival check to make sure no arrival left behind a negative amount of oil in the plant.

My expected output would contain something like:

```
Arrival Date    Arrival Capacity    Plant Oil Amount At Date   Remaining
2014-01-05          Y                         X                X-Y
2014-01-10          Y                         X                X-Y
```

If not also including dates where nothing arrived, just to log the amount of Oil produced.

How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Too broad. Please try and be a little more specific with the requirements.

Comment: I've added an example of my expected output and a bit more info but i'm unsure what other information you might want to see

Comment: This, among other things, is unclear: *You know that something is going to arrive every day to take oil from the plant, and they are each going to have a unique size and amount they take from the tanker. You know what those sizes and amounts are.* In what table are these data stored, how is the table defined, what is the meaning of the attributes?

Comment: I think i've added that info now, let me know if that helps make it clear. I'm still new to postgreSQL so sorry if i'm unclear.